# Tartaglia distribution

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I do not know if this question is elementary of advanced. Let me start by describing the two dimensional case in word.

Take the Tartaglia (or Pascal, or Bernoulli, or whatever name you want to give it) triangle, and draw a line starting from the vertex. At the $m$-th line of the triangle, consider the ratio $R_m$ of the sum of numbers on the left of the line divided by $2^m$, so divided by the sum of all items on the $m$-th line. I would like to know the limit of $R_m$ according to the slope of the line. More specifically, I would like to know when this limit is one.

In symbols, the question reads as follow. Let the slope $S$ be a number between $0$ and $1$. Let
$$
R_m=2^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{ \lfloor Sm \rfloor}\binom{m}{k} \,.
$$
What is the infimum of the $S$ such that $\lim_{m\to \infty} R_m=1$?

I also have the multi-dimensional version of this question. Let $k=(k_1,\dots , k_{\ell})$ be coordinates on $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$. Let $S_m$ be the subset of $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$ defined by $\sum_{i=1}^{\ell} k_i=m$.
Recall that 
$$
\sum_{k\in S_m}\frac{m!}{k_1!\cdots k_{\ell}!} =\ell^m\,.
$$
Now take a convex cone $C$ in $\mathbb{R}_+^{\ell}$ and look of the ratio
$$
R_m=\ell^{-m}\sum_{k\in C \cap S_m}\frac{m!}{k_1!\cdots k_{\ell}!}
$$
and for the limit $R=\lim_{m\to \infty}R_m$.

For which convex cones $C$ is the limit $R$ equal to $1$? I am particularly interested in the cones containing one axis, e.g. the half line passing trough the origin and say $(1,0,\dots , 0)$.

Thanks

Comment: For any increasing function $w(m)$ almost all the row sum appears within $w(m)m^{1/2}$ of the centre.  So $R_m\to 0$ if $S<\frac12$ and $R_m\to 1$ if $S>\frac12$.  On the boundary, where $S=\frac12$, then of course $R_m\to\frac12$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Sorry I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you explain it better? You can make it also as an answer if you wish. References are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The values $2^{-m}\binom mk$ are the probabilities of the binomial distribution $\text{Bin}(m,\frac12)$ so the mean is $m/2$ and the variance is $m/4$. The values are concentrated within any increasing multiple of the standard deviation $m^{1/2}/2$ from the mean.  Any constant slope $S$ which is not exactly $\frac12$ will pass one side or the other of that region.

Comment: So the answer is any convex cone which contains $(1,1,\dots , 1)$ in the interior?

Comment: For fixed $\ell$, the largest terms occur when $k_1,\ldots,k_\ell$ are about equal, so a cone including all of those will have almost everything.  If you need more details I suggest you post your question to https://math.stackexchange.com as it is not a research level question.

Comment: Thanks, I work on a different field, so I did not know if this were a research level question. Thanks a lot.